# Convert an object with array to only an array

Tags: c#, arrays, json

So I have a problem where after Deserialization my JSON converts to an object (There no other way for this). In my object there is another object called "Content".

This objects holds an array but since this also needs to be converted to an object it comes out as this:

```
object Content = {[
      {
        "geofence_id": 44896,
        "name": "WAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
      },
      {
        "geofence_id": 44920,
        "name": "Work"
      }
    ]}
```

(For this is also no other way).

Now I wish to know how to convert this object to an object array.

I tried:

```
GeofenceResponse[] arr = Content as GeofenceResponse[];
```

Where content.Content is the object shown in the top snippet and GeofenceResponse[] is the objectarray.

But this resulted in arr being null.

A GeofenceResponse looks like this:

```
class GeofenceResponse : Response
{
    public int Geofence_id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A response is just:

```
class Response
{
}
```

Since I have multiple different ones.

But I get multiple of them in the Contect object.

Comment: If you are able to present this as a complete code sample that we can copy and paste into our Visual Studio, we may be able to solve your problem faster. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @mjwills Would this suffice?

Comment: The `object Content` code doesn't seem to compile @Jelmer.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON seems invalid {[...]} is not valid per http://www.json.org/
BTW valid object wrapping of array is {"content":[...]}

You should not wrap the array into object but deserialize the array directly:

```
string json = @"[
  {
    'Name': 'Product 1',
    'ExpiryDate': '2000-12-29T00:00Z',
    'Price': 99.95,
    'Sizes': null
  },
  {
    'Name': 'Product 2',
    'ExpiryDate': '2009-07-31T00:00Z',
    'Price': 12.50,
    'Sizes': null
  }
]";
List<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Product>>(json);
```

Sample taken from https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm

Comment: It's not a json object anymore, it is already an object. And I can't deserialize only the array since it's a child variable of the json.

Comment: if you have POCO already, then it has to contain some property. Use your debugger to get the property and its type. If it is string => a json array, use it instead of "json" in my deserialization example, if it is already typed, then you cast it to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to find the answer myself, all I had to do was:

```
GeofenceResponse[] arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GeofenceResponse[]>(content.Content.ToString(), jsonSettings);
```

This resulted in a perfectly filled array of GeofenceResponses